# Segfault during C++ array deallocation

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, valgrind, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a weird problem in memory deallocation.

I have the following code for class MemoryPartition:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include "memorypartition.h"

MemoryPartition::MemoryPartition(int maxSize) {
    this->partitionArray = new char[maxSize];

    memset(this->partitionArray, ((int) '$'), maxSize);

    this->maxSize = maxSize;
    this->isFree = true;
}

MemoryPartition::~MemoryPartition() {
    delete[] this->partitionArray;
    this->partitionArray = NULL;
    maxSize = 0;
}

void MemoryPartition::setFree(bool isFree) {
    this->isFree = isFree;
}

bool MemoryPartition::getFree() {
    return this->isFree;
}

int MemoryPartition::getMaxSize() {
    return this->maxSize;
}

void MemoryPartition::getPartitionArray() {
    for(int i = 0;i < maxSize;i++) {
        std::cout << partitionArray[i] << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

and the following code for MemoryManager:

```
#include "memorymanager.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

MemoryManager::MemoryManager() {
}

MemoryManager::~MemoryManager() {
    memory.clear();
}

void MemoryManager::defmem(int bytes) {
    MemoryPartition *memPartition;
    int maxMemorySize = bytes;

    while(maxMemorySize != 0) {
        int partitionSize = this->randomPartitionSize(maxMemorySize);

        memPartition = new MemoryPartition(partitionSize);
        this->memory.push_back(*memPartition);

        std::cout << memPartition->getMaxSize() << std::endl;
        memPartition->getPartitionArray();

        maxMemorySize -= partitionSize;
        delete memPartition;
        memPartition = NULL;
    }
}

int MemoryManager::randomPartitionSize(int maxSize) {
    int value;

    srand(time(NULL));
    value = (rand() % maxSize) + 1;

    return value;
}
```

and I'm getting a weird at delete[] in MemoryPartition destructor. Valgrind is telling me there are 13 frees and 10 allocs, but I can't see a reason why this delete[] would be called 3x.

Anyone see the problem I couldn't figure out?

Thanks in advance.

[]'s,

Comment: Well the problem is not in THAT code.  Post up the code where MemoryPartition is used and maybe we can help you.

Comment: Perhaps you need to define your copy constructor and copy assignment operator?

Comment: The problem must be happening elsewhere.  Does Valgrind report any heap corruption?  Is there anywhere else where you allocate/deallocate `partitionArray`

Comment: Actually, when I comment the delete[] line the problem stops showing up. Anyway, I'm gonna post the code you asked too.

Comment: `((int) '$')` should be `static_cast<int>('$')`.  You don't have to set the pointer to `NULL` after you're done with it.  You won't be able to use the pointer anymore if you're in the dtor, anyhow (so its pretty obvious any code using it would be wrong, in a code review).  Same with `maxSize = 0`.  You should also use a `size_t` for your sizes, rather than int.

Comment: Great guys, I solved it! Thx everyone for the tips! :D Just defined my own copy constructor as I needed it and everything now works pretty fine ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its impossible to tell from the code above.

But my guess is that you need to define the copy constructor and assignment operator.

See Rule of 4 (Google/Wiki it).

Try the following:

```
class MemoryPartition
{
    // Just add these two lines (keep them private)
    MemoryPartition(MemoryPartition const&);            // Don't define.
    MemoryPartition& operator=(MemoryPartition const&); // Don't define.
<CLASS STUFF AS BEFORE>
};
```

Compile the code now. If it fails because the above are private then you have accidentally made a copy of the object somewhere and are doing a double delete on the pointer.

Comment: I'm guessing that's the case as well.

Comment: Yep, it failed. Gonna figure out where did I do the wrong stuff.

Comment: Yup, that's it.  The `push_back` on the container is making copies.

Comment: Just noticed that. I'm gonna change the approach to solve the issue.

Comment: @SebastianK: Sorry. I keep calling it the rule of 4 as you need to override the `4 compiler generated methods`. But I have heard it refereed to as the rule of 3 (The lazy version :-) ).

Comment: Destructor, copy constructor, assignment operator. What is the fourth method you refer to?

Comment: @Storm: If you have a C++0x compiler, you can replace `push_back(some_type(a, b, c))` with `emplace_back(a, b, c)` and get rid of the unnecessary copy.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Does this help? Your object can still potentially be copied in other situations. So the underlying problem needs to be fixed before we start to try and optimize usage patterns.